# can't use two bundles with ehcache in karaf container

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, ehcache, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I'm using the Karaf (actually Aetos) OSGi container.  I want to have two bundles that use ehcache.  Apparently, when the second bundle starts its cache, the cache of the first bundle is stopped.

When the first one is installed, there is no problem.  It runs fine.

When I install the second one I get a stack trace like this:

```
2014-03-25 20:38:18,758 | ERROR | rint Extender: 2 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 9 - org.apache.aries.blueprint - 0.3.2 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle DataProviderLoadFX
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to instantiate components
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:635)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:337)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:230)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)[:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)[:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)[:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)[:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)[:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)[:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)[:1.6.0_41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[:1.6.0_41]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:768)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:722)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:64)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:813)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:787)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:768)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:722)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:64)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:219)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:147)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:631)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    ... 10 more
```

Then I update that second bundle and it starts up just fine.  However, when I then exercise the cache on the first bundle, the cache begins to fail with this stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke method: handleFTPDeliveryRequest(${property.requestId},${property.duplicate}) on null due to: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The DRS_RequestServiceLoadSensitivity_jdbcOneHourToLiveCache Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression$OgnlInvokeProcessor.process(BeanExpression.java:285)
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:114)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The DRS_RequestServiceLoadSensitivity_jdbcOneHourToLiveCache Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:4290)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2731)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1610)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1591)
    at com.windlogics.tsunami.drs.requestservice.LdfxDAO.checkDuplicaeFTPRequest(LdfxDAO.java:843)
    at com.windlogics.tsunami.drs.requestservice.RequestProcessor.handleFTPDeliveryRequest(RequestProcessor.java:284)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:341)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:238)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression$InvokeProcessor.process(BeanExpression.java:189)
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression$OgnlInvokeProcessor.process(BeanExpression.java:281)
    ... 93 more
```

The ehcache config files are in the bundles.  They are identical except for the names of the ehcache and caches and the names of the files themselves are even different.

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
    name="DRS_RequestServiceLoadSensitivity" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <transactionManagerLookup class="net.sf.ehcache.transaction.manager.DefaultTransactionManagerLookup" properties="jndiName=java:/TransactionManager"
        propertySeparator=";" />

    <cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="" properties="" />


    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="0" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="1200" timeToLiveSeconds="1200">
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="DRS_RequestServiceLoadSensitivity_jdbcOneHourToLiveCache" maxBytesLocalHeap="100M" maxBytesLocalDisk="200M" eternal="false"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20" timeToLiveSeconds="3600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" transactionalMode="off">
</ehcache>
```

I'm using the following bean as a factory:

```
public class CacheManagerFactory {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CacheManagerFactory.class);

    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    private String configFilename = "ehcache.xml";

    private Bundle bundle;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            URL url = bundle.getEntry(configFilename);
            in = url.openStream();
            cacheManager = CacheManager.create(in);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.warn("", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void dispose() {
        cacheManager.shutdown();
    }

    public Cache getCache(String name) {
        return cacheManager.getCache(name);
    }

    public CacheManager getCacheManager() {
        return cacheManager;
    }

    public void setBundle(Bundle bundle) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

    public void setConfigFilename(String configFilename) {
        this.configFilename = configFilename;
    }

}
```

Here is the excerpt from the blueprint.xml files where I use the factory:

```
    <bean id="cacheManagerFactory" class="com.windlogics.tsunami.drs.dataprovider.CacheManagerFactory" init-method="afterPropertiesSet" destroy-method="dispose">
        <property name="bundle" ref="blueprintBundle" />
        <property name="configFilename" value="DRS_RequestServiceLoadSensitivity_ehcache.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="com.windlogics.tsunami.drs.dataprovider.LdfxDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="loadFXDataSource" />
        <property name="cache">
            <bean factory-ref="cacheManagerFactory" factory-method="getCache">
                <argument value="DRS_RequestServiceLoadSensitivity_jdbcOneHourToLiveCache" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I have this in the pom.xml files:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I tried renaming both ehcache.xml config files (one in each bundle).  I uninstalled both bundles.  The first one re-installed fine.  When I installed the second I got a NPE and it failed to start:

    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:768)[9:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]

Then when I updated it (same bundle) it started.  I'll test now to see if it is working.

Comment: Tested again.  It is always the first bundle that starts that begins to fail when the second one is started.  It appears that when the second cache starts, the first on is stopped.

Comment: This seems related: https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-969

Comment: I'm gathering that I need to put ehcache into its own bundle.  Does this mean I can have only one config file?  I guess I can add caches programmatically.  What's the best practice on this?